# How to make blink like animation by changing color of imageview?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I am making a music game. If the user press hint button to know which key to press. I want to show a blink effect on the `ImageView` by changing the `bitmap` color programmatically from one color to another repeatedly(switching between two colors) for 1 second.

This is how I am changing the color of bitmap programmatically:

```
nextImage.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

I think we can use `Handler` for this but I am not getting how to product blink effect.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the blink effect by the following way:

```
final String[] colors = {"#00BCD4","#FFFFFF","#00BCD4","#FFFFFF","#00BCD4","#FFFFFF","#00BCD4","#FFFFFF"};
                        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                            final int j = i;
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    nextImage.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(colors[j]), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                                }
                            },200 * j);
```

Hope this might help someone else. If there are better ways of doing it. Do suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you can use handler

```
Structure
 -onClick 
   -change color
  wait 1 second
   -change color
   action() //what click shuld do on btn
```

Comment: I really like your answer and even I have same thing in my head. But I wanna see implementation. I am not able to achieve that effect thats why posted here.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want is like this.

create 3 drawable files.

first drawable

//color1.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:shape="rectangle">
 <solid android:color="#hexcodeofcolor1" />
 <corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dip"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"  
    android:topRightRadius="8dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dip"/>
 </shape>
```

color2.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:shape="rectangle">
 <solid android:color="#hexcodeofcolor2" />
 <corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dip"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"  
    android:topRightRadius="8dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dip"/>
  </shape>
```

imageviewtempgif.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <animation-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false"
android:useLevel="true">

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/hexcodeofcolor1"
    android:duration="500"
    android:useLevel="true"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/hexcodeofcolor2"
    android:duration="500"
    android:useLevel="true"/>
  </animation-list>
```

And in your code

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageviewtempgif);
    ((Animatable) imgWiFi.getDrawable()).start();
```

Once you done with the animation you can set whatever background you want.

may be something like this.

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageviewtempgif);
    ((Animatable) imgWiFi.getDrawable()).start();
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override
  public void run() {
  //set to normal background.
  }
  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this blending two colors like this keep changing this two colors

```
/**
     * Blend {@code color1} and {@code color2} using the given ratio.
     *
     * @param ratio of which to blend. 0.0 will return {@code color1}, 0.5 will give an even blend,
     *              1.0 will return {@code color2}.
     */
    public static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
        final float inverseRatio = 1f - ratio;
        float a = (Color.alpha(color1) * inverseRatio) + (Color.alpha(color2) * ratio);
        float r = (Color.red(color1) * inverseRatio) + (Color.red(color2) * ratio);
        float g = (Color.green(color1) * inverseRatio) + (Color.green(color2) * ratio);
        float b = (Color.blue(color1) * inverseRatio) + (Color.blue(color2) * ratio);
        return Color.argb((int) a, (int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
    }
```

Comment: I am not asking to blend colours. I just wanted to switch between two different colours. Anyway I got the solution.

Comment: @XoXo Would you like to share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create a color file in res > color folder, namely `icon_click_color.xml` with followed code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/colorDefault" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/colorPressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/colorPressed" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorDefault" />
</selector>
```

Then, in you ImageView, set the tint property, for example:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_setting"
    app:tint="@color/icon_click_color">
</ImageView>
```